# How small can the sum of the interior angles of a triangle in hyperbolic geometry get? Is there a lower bound?

Tags: geometry, triangles, hyperbolic-geometry, angle

I know that in Euclidean geometry, the sum of the interior angles of a triangle is exactly $\pi$.

In  hyperbolic geometry, I know that the sum of the interior angles of a triangle is $\leq \pi$, and I know that there exist triangles in hyperbolic geometry with interior angles that sum to strictly less than $\pi$.

However, what I don't know is ...

> How small can the sum of the interior angles of a triangle in hyperbolic geometry get? Is there a lower bound?

Is there a hyperbolic triangle with interior angle sum equal to, say, $1/10000000$? I suspect it is something nice like the angles have to add up to be at least $\pi/2$ but I don't know if that's true.

Comment: I can't figure out a good way to represent it, but you can have a triangle with zero angle measure. In the Half plane representation of hyperbolic geometry, this consists of a half circle of Radius $2R$ with two half circles of radius $R$ inside it, all of them tangent to each other. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_half-plane_model) wikipedia article for visuals.

Comment: It is possible to create a triangle on the hyperbolic plane with three angles of measure 0.  In fact this is an "ideal triangle."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_triangle

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Like this? https://i.imgur.com/scKQ8S6.png

Comment: Yeah, although @DougM has already linked an article that has better pictures. It's a fair point that ideal triangles don't properly live in the hyperbolic plane. So the correct statement is probably that total angle measure $\theta$ satisfies $0 < \theta \leq \pi$.

Comment: In the hyperbolic plane, one can have a triangle with angles $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ iff $\alpha,\beta,\gamma>0$ and $\alpha+\beta+\gamma<\pi$.

Comment: $0$.  You can get a triangle with all three angles equal to $0$.

Comment: In reading these comments you should keep in mind that an "ideal triangle" is not an actual triangle, having three actual vertices which are points in the hyperbolic plane. At an actual vertex of an actual triangle, the angle will never be equal to zero. The most straightforward answer to your question is in the comment of @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Worth noting also that the existence of even one triangle with interior angle sum exactly equal to $\pi$ is equivalent to Euclid's parallel postulate ...

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry if this should be a comment and not an answer: please advise). There is no lower bound. See, for example, [Existence of triangles with three arbitrarily small angles in Archimedian Neutral Geometry, (e.g. in hyperbolic geometry). From baby Hartshorne](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3489295/296521) for a rough sketch of a synthetic proof.

Comment: Eh, probably should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

Comment

Equilateral triangle on Poincare disc, each vertex zero (spike) angle.

Angle defect$\pi.$

[image]